# How to obtain a slanted-curve for my div? Like one shown below

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is a `div` that stretches the whole mobile screen; I'd want it to have a tilted curve(as shown in image) from top-right to top-left. I tried `border-radius` but that didn't work as expected.
Is there a way to do this using CSS?

Comment: You can use [css transform rotate](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for that.

Comment: I think u should use svgs instead.

Comment: If i use rotate, the contents inside would also rotate right?

Comment: i cant use svg, its the div i need to get a slanted-curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Perhaps `clip-path` property might work for you.....**

```css
.container {
  background: #f6eee0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% -2%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Here is the updated snippet including the curve, if you need to increase/decrease the size of the curve just play around with the negative value in the `clip-path` property until you find the sweet spot and suits you the best...***

Comment: Hey Uzair, This Helps a lot, Thanks. btw Is there a way to get the Curve too? (If you notice the provided image, its not a Straight line, has a small curve..)

Comment: Hey @gopalprabhu I thought there was a curve but due to the color of the image, it was kind of hard to see, and yes the curve is indeed possible, I am updating my code for the same.......